# i need the help for connecting mysql with java in ubuntu OS

Tags: java, jdbc

I have my java application and try to connect with mysql database.But i can't able to get the output,i am getting the Exception error.I think i am not able to connect with the driver.My OS is Linux(Ubuntu).

---

```
nikki@nikki-laptop:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9) (6b20-1.9-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)

nikki@nikki-laptop:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java


nikki@nikki-laptop:~$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar:/home/nikki/temp/src/jclass
```

---

My jdk path is   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre

---

My Java program is

```
import java.sql.*;
class Query1
 {
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
 {
 try
 {  // the mysql driver string
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
  // the mysql url = "jdbc:mysql://THE_HOST/THE_DATABASE";

  //String url = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

  String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mylib_db";

  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"nikki","dkm007");
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 //ResultSet rs;
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select title from Book_dim where cost=435.89");
 while (rs.next())
 {
 String titlename = rs.getString("title");
 System.out.println(titlename + "\n");
 }
  conn.close();

 }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
 }
```

---

My output is

```
-    -      -      -             -
nikki@nikki-laptop:~/Documents/Chinu/mydbP$ javac Query1.java
nikki@nikki-laptop:~/Documents/Chinu/mydbP$ java Query1
Got an exception! 
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

---

I didn't added any driver...i don't know which Driver should i use .How can i add driver?
If possible plz send me the reply.

Comment: @Petar. You've got the power!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Driver to the classpath of you application.

```
nikki@nikki-laptop:~/Documents/Chinu/mydbP$ java -cp /path/to/mysqldriver.jar Query1
```

Comment: i do not know how to set path for connector-java-5.0.8  .My mysql- connector  has been downloaded to  (/home/nikki/temp/src/jclass/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8).My jdk has been in (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk).If i am writing to show classpath it gives..........

Comment: i had already downloaded and it's in (/home/nikki/temp/src/jclass/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8).My jdk is in(/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk).But my CLASSPATH shows (bash: :/usr/share/java/mysql.jar:/home/nikki/temp/src/jclass: No such file or directory) My JAVA_HOME SHOWS (nikki@nikki-laptop:~$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java: No such file or directory)Is it right?
how can i set path?

Comment: @user490261. Please RTFM at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html

Answer (score 1):

You likely haven't included the mysql driver on the classpath.  Download the JDBC driver from mysql and put the mysql-connector-java-[version]-bin.jar file on your classpath.

It would also be helpful to know more about just what exception is being thrown.  Here is how you do that:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The OP does this, the output is : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: No, that's e.getMessage(), which doesn't tell you the class of the exception.  e.printStackTrace() does.

Comment: +1.  Just add the printout of exception message as well.  In situations like this you often need both.

Comment: missed the distinction.  In this case though, the error displayed described the error completely - no jdbc driver in the classpath (but your suggestion was/is helpful)

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
 at Query1.main(Query1.java:11)
It shows the above errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check these references out:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-examples.html

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 0):

Download the [mysql jdbc driver](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) and add it to your classpath.

Comment: i had already downloaded and it's in (/home/nikki/temp/src/jclass/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8).My jdk is in(/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk).But my CLASSPATH shows (bash: :/usr/share/java/mysql.jar:/home/nikki/temp/src/jclass: No such file or directory) My JAVA_HOME SHOWS (nikki@nikki-laptop:~$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java: No such file or directory)Is it right?how can i set path?